# How to upsert child object with master details realationship to another customobject,which one master as opportunity

Tags: master-detail, data-import

I have one custom object(named: `Class__c`),it has master another custom object (`Plan__c`). Further this Plan has Standard object Opportunity as master.

I have Class.csv files which contains classes objects.
This csv file also has external id of Plan__c object.

When i am importing Classes object and using following releationship:

```
planClassId=External_Plan_Class_Key__c
planId=plan__r\:External_Plan_Key__c
```

Where External_Plan_Class_Key__c is the external key for Class object and
External_Plan_Key__c is the external key for plan object.

It is throwing error

> required filed plan__c is missing.plan__c is the master filed on class object for plans.

I was expecting like,if load will first match external keys for class if it does not exist it should insert it.

In our Buisness:plan is always come in class.csv files which will always exst in salesforce.(no upsert for plan,only update were there).

Still it is asking for plan__c missing field.
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
Arun sharma

Comment: You want to perform `update` with external id ? either use `Id+update` or `external_id+upsert` combination

Comment: could you please help me how would mapping would go.External_Plan_Class_Key__c and plan__r\:External_Plan_Key__c..