# Issue in upserting child object with master external id

Tags: upsert

I have one custom object named `Class__c`, which has one master relationship with another custom object named `Plan__c`.

I have Class.csv files which contains classes objects. This csv file also has external id of the parent `Plan__c` record.

When I import `Class__c` records using the following relationship:

```
planClassId=External_Plan_Class_Key__c
planId=plan__r\:External_Plan_Key__c
```

Where `External_Plan_Class_Key__c` is the external key for `Class__c` object and `External_Plan_Key__c` is the external key for `Plan__c` object.

It is throwing error

> required field plan__c is missing.

I was expecting that if load will first match external keys for class if it does not exist it should insert it.

Our business plan always comes in Class.csv files which will always exist in salesforce. We do not plan to support upsert, only update.

Still it is asking for `Plan__c` missing field.

Comment: I found same question from user here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112363/how-to-upsert-child-object-with-master-details-realationship-to-another-customob

Comment: Thanks Martin for quick response.Is there any other way apart from trigger and job which can be implemented.And yes that question was also posted by me,i thought i was not able to explain problem in that.

Comment: If you don't mind me taking a step back, why not support upsert? That's the easiest way to work with external ids.

Comment: We are doing upsert only.Process is upsert.

Comment: Your org Validation is preventing not the upsert job itself i think

Comment: Since you assume all Plan should be there, I recommend downloading all the Ids and External Ids using data loader, fill up those plan Ids and upsert again (assuming all external ids have apprte plan ids)

Comment: Thanks Kartiksseva for holding with so long..The Issue is  we are getting csv files at our location.then automatic batch scheduler IBM Tivoli is kicking the Apex load process through command line. Requirement is no manual intervation should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to mimic your scenario, and I was able to load the data. I guess the problem is with your Mapping file only. If there is a existing Plan record with the external Id you specified in csv, it should pickup the master record accordingly.

And this behaviour is something which is not a Org specific, there is no different setting we have to do for it.
Please let me know if you need any other info.